# What is the the word refers to heating and cooling at the same time?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am going to open a new store, which contains heating and cooling devices. What is one word that refers to both? I want to use it in the name of the store, for exmaple:

> *{Heating and Cooling}* Supplies

Comment: Maybe *Ambitemp* (short for ambient or mix temperature) or *Omnitemp* which stands for all kinds of temperature?

Comment: _Climate control (devices)_?

Comment: Ac-heater-fan....

Comment: 'Thermostatically controlled'.

Comment: How would you use the word in a sentence?

Comment: (word) then name of Store ..

Comment: Check in Amazon, if they don't have a single word for those type of products then it doesn't exist, "heating and cooling appliances" seem to work just fine to me.

Comment: [thermoregulator](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/thermoregulator).

Comment: Does HVAC make sense?

Comment: Please be clear, nothing could ever refer to *heating and cooling at the same time*. It might well refer to heating *or* cooling, but d'you think they're the same thing?

If you mean *what could refer to either heating or cooling* that would be *temperature change*.

Consider: *To provide heating* and *to provide cooling* and *to provide temperature change*.

Comment: Yeah, certainly if you're heating and cooling the same space at the same time then you're wasting money and accelerating global warming.  "Climate controlled" (with or without hyphen, as you prefer) is the adjective for a space where the temperature is automatically controlled by either heating and cooling as required.  If you wish to refer to the equipment that does the work it's "HVAC" equipment, and that term encompasses stuff like coolers for foodstuffs as well.

Answer (score 2):

You could consider **HVAC** which stands for:

> Heating, Ventilation and Air Conditioning

<sup>[acronymfinder.com](https://www.acronymfinder.com/HVAC.html)</sup>

"Air Conditioning" provides both cooling and humidity control <sup>[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HVAC#Air_conditioning)</sup>.

Your store name could then be:

> HVAC Supplies

or

> Darwish HVAC

Answer (score 1):

**Climate-controlled**, adjective, according to TFD, OLD and MW:

> "Having the temperature and humidity regulated by a heating and cooling system"[1](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/climate-controlled)
>
> "(Of a car, building, enclosure, etc.) having the interior temperature, humidity, and airflow artificially controlled."[3](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/climate-controlled)
>
> "having or providing artificial control of air temperature, humidity, and movement"[2](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/climate-controlled)

Examples in a sentence / excerpt:

> "a climate-controlled office"[2](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/climate-controlled)
>
> "a climate-controlled vehicle"[2](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/climate-controlled)

There is also the word **climate control**, a noun, according to dictionary.com:

> "a thermostat for controlling a heating or air-conditioning system".[4](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/climate-control)
>
> "Climate control is a system for controlling the temperature inside a vehicle."[5](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/climate-control)

Sometimes *climate control* is used only for airconditioning specifically, but you could solve that by adding context, consider the following:

> We offer *climate control*, for all you *climate-controlled* office needs.

Another example (climate control might imply you also include humidity controlling, etc.):

> We offer *climate control*, for all your *heating[6](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/heating) and cooling*[7](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/cooling) needs.